# How to implement 'BottomNavigation' element in a nativescript application?

Tags: android, angular, nativescript, bottomnavigationview

I have a working project written with angular nativescript, and now i want to add some tabs using 'BottomNavigation'. I looked in the documentation and it seemed pretty simple, but when i added the code to my project all of the tabs just overlayed on each other and i didn't saw any tabs, as if i just put the pages one on another. What am i missing? What should i do in order to use bottom navigation? I tried to create a new helloe world project and just add the bottom navigation but i got the same result. However, when i created a 'tabs' project it did had proper tabs.

I suspect its have somthing to do with the {N} version. I recently updated to the latest version (8.1.5) and there are a lot of troubles with it. Does bottom navigation still supported on this version? How can i make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i found the solution. In case someone in the future will face the same problem:
It is a version problem. Since version 8 you should add the package manualy as described here:
https://github.com/nativescript-community/ui-material-components/tree/master/packages/bottom-navigation#installation